# How is this data structure called?

Tags: data-structures, tree

Few month ago my co-worker showed me the data structure that is basically a tree but with some additional data that makes some of the operations perform faster and efficiently. Only I have left is a diagram showing possible schema of this DS.

[image]

Comment: The keys look low and high limits of a range, containing all ranges in the respective sub-tree. I don't see use for `id`. `depth` seems pointless picturing traversals starting at the root. I don't see any support for choosing children *not* to visit.

Comment: Have you asked your coworker? Also a lot of tree implementations are not really different in the data they store but rather in the algorithms they use to access and modify the tree, so without code (or descriptions) of these we can't really tell much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tree that has been *augmented* with a kind of pre- and postorder information. Besides the trivial Depth we can also derive:

- The pre-order sequence number of a given node is (LKey + Depth + 1) / 2, where the root gets number 1, its left child 2, ... and the rightmost leaf 13.
- Similarly, the post-order sequence nunmber of a given node is (RKey + Depth + 1) / 2, where the leftmost left gets number 1, its parent 2, ... and the root 13.
- The size of the tree rooted by a given node is (RKey - LKey + 1) / 2, so for instance the node with id 8 roots a tree that has (25-18+1)/2 = 4 nodes. And so also all leaves have RKey - LKey = 1.

This structure is only useful when the tree is static, in the sense that no nodes are added or deleted from it, because those operations would have a O() time complexity. But if those operations are not relevant, then this structure can provide information about a node which otherwise would need you to traverse the tree.

Also, this structure would need some *payload* for each node (i.e. a value), as otherwise it doesn't store much more than the tree's shape. In practice you would want to store some *data* that has some business meaning.

Note that the Id information is just a unique identifier: we cannot see it from just this example, but it might give you the order in which nodes were added to the tree, so that it is guaranteed that a node's id is greater than that of its parent, and that the root has Id 1.